# Not able to call values from feature file in Typescript implemented using Cucumber Framework

Tags: angular, typescript, cucumber

Not able to call values from feature file in Typescript implemented using Cucumber Framework tool Protractor. How can i call these Examples values in my typescript method in When block.

Code for Feature file

Feature: Navigate to calculator site and add two number

Scenario: Add two number using calculator site

Given Navigate to calculator site url "cal"

When Provide two numbers to add first number  and

Then Click on add button on calculator site

Scenario Outline: Provide parameters

Examples:
| key1 | key2 |

```
| 2  | 3  |

|2    |60 |
```

Code of When block

When('Provide two numbers to add first number  and ', async (key1:string,key2:string)=> {

```
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

await cal.firstEditBox.sendKeys(key1);

await cal.secondEditBox.sendKeys(key2);
```

});

on Executing it is giving me Error

1. Scenario: Add two number using calculator site # features\demo.feature:3

   √ Given Navigate to calculator site url "cal" # stepDefinations\steps.ts:10

   × When Provide two numbers to add first number  and  # stepDefinations\steps.ts:16

   ```
   function has 2 arguments, should have 0 (if synchronous or returning a promise) or 1 (if accepting a callback)
   ```

   - Then Click on add button on calculator site # stepDefinations\steps.ts:24

   √ After # node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\resultsCapturer.js:27

Answer (score 0):

```
Feature: Navigate to calculator site and add two number
Scenario: Add two number using calculator site
Given Navigate to calculator site url "cal"
When Provide two numbers "<key1>" and "<key2>"
Then Click on add button on calculator site
Scenario Outline: Provide parameters

Examples: 
| key1 | key2 |
| 2    |  3   |
| 2    | 60   |
```

```
When('Provide two numbers {string} and {string}', async (key1:string,key2:string)=> {

// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

await cal.firstEditBox.sendKeys(key1);

await cal.secondEditBox.sendKeys(key2);
});
```

Comment: ? When Provide two numbers to add first number <key1> and <key2>
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         When('Provide two numbers to add first number <key1> and <key2>', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });

Comment: it is again asking to give step definition of When block as i changed <key> to <string> please find error i have given

Comment: Your feature file step should be as it is the step definition. Have you copied the given code as it is ? If possible share the link to your project.

Comment: Feature: Navigate to calculator site and add two number
Scenario: Add two number using calculator site
Given Navigate to calculator site url "cal"
When Provide two numbers "<key1>" and "<key2>"
Then Click on add button on calculator site
Scenario Outline: Provide parameters

Examples: 
| key1 | key2 |
| 2    |  3   |
| 2    | 60   |      This is feature file in when step it says <key1> and <key2> when i changed as suggested by you <key> to string it gave error to re-dfine When block definition

Comment: Got it my mistake <key> should have been defined as "<key>". thanks for your support. Your answer was absolutely correct.

Comment: Did all same now it is entering <key1> and <key2> in calculator text boxes instead taking values from parameters